# Create javascript variable with button click no jQuery

Tags: javascript, random

I am wondering how I would create a variable on the click of a button, so I could make a random name generator, like this:

```
    <input class="varValue" placeholder="Name to be generated">
    <button class="createVar></button>
    <script>
        var createVar = document.querySelector(".createVar");
        var varValue = document.querySelector(".varValue");
        var nameNumber = 0;
        var getValue = function(){
            varValue.value = //new var with ascending values or something;
            nameNumber = nameNumber + 1;
        };
        createValue.addEventListener("click", getValue(), false");
        //then some Math.random using, nameNumber, anyway I'll figure it out
    </script>
```

So how would I make the variables on the click of the button?

Also no jQuery please.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the onclick event?

Comment: addEventListener second argument is a function, if getValue is a function, you need to send getValue, not run getValue().

Comment: You question is not clear . **varValue.value**  will throw an error. It is not an object

Comment: No I just don't know how to create varibles with the click of a button

Answer (score 0):

The function `getValue()` [which I don't see declared, so it should be declared somewhere] is in charge of any new logic attached to that event in this case. 
To create and do something with those variables simply do it right inside that function.

I believe you meant `createVar.addEventListener()` and not createValue

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change createVar() to getValue, but I just want to create, and besides those errors, I was wondering just how to give the value on the click of a button a variable and add to the total count so I could randomly generate.